# Customize Dataprod workflows

Tags: google-cloud-platform, workflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I use workflows with Dataproc. There are 3 things I'd like to do:

- instantiate a single workflow step. Sometime a workflow crashes, and I don't want to run the whole workflow again, only at a / from a given step
- parameters are limited. Sometimes there are URL templates that I'd like to define in workflow, a parameter being only a part of it.

  ```
  jobs:
  - sparkJob:
  args:
  - --myarg
  - gs://base-url/the-param-I-want-to-parametrize.csv
  ```
- from a workflow, I'd like to disable a task in the scheduler, and also call a Cloud Function, is this possible?

Is there a way to achieve those? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reaching out. We intentionally didn't implement some features until we had clear demand.

I would suggest filing a feature request for #1 and #2 with a use case at [1].

Supporting job retries (via Restartable Jobs) or adding policies like proceed-on-failure in Workflows seem reasonable.

I am not sure what you're requesting in #3 (which scheduler)? Cloud Functions are triggered via HTTP requests, files in GCS or PubSub notifications. You should be able to use pyspark with a client library to trigger via either of these paths.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Answer (score 0):

You could be better off using a more generic orchestration solution - [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/) (managed [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org)) instead of Dataproc Workflows. It has all the features that you need and supports [Dataproc](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.html) too.

Comment: Cloud composer looks very good, but this is a billing solution.